# MonoTouch: Namespaces allowed

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

We are writing the specs for a C# project which will be consumed by a `MonoTouch` and `MonoDroid` UI. The programmer knows little about Mono and will be using `Visual Studio only` so we need to let them know what .NET namespaces are `off limits`.

What are the guidelines in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a *perfect* solution but there are things you can try to make it easier, e.g.

- Create a Silverlight 4 project and do not use `System.Windows.[Web].dll`;
- Create a Portable Project Library (v1) project and avoid using MEF (System.Composition);
- Use one (there a few) Visual Studio plugin(s) like this [one](https://github.com/jamiebriant/VsMono).

That should solve most of the issues. Rebuilding, from time to time, using MonoTouch will ensure you find the few missing cases.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific list, here is the update on what can/cannot be used depending on what version of Mono you are using.

http://www.go-mono.com/status/